# Show a Messagebox if program is ran for the first time in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

When a user runs the program for the first time I want a message box to show up.

I was thinking of something like this:

```c
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(firstTime)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
   }
```

How could I get my program to display a message box when a user launches the program for the first time in c#?

Comment: If you need a per user settings, the best way to go would be to use settings (from the System.Configuration). It allows you to save user settings in the user local or roaming profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a parameter to the application settings.

Go to the solution explorer in the section `Properties` and double click on `Settings.settings`.

Add a parameter named for example `IsFirstLaunch` and set type to bool with value `True`.

Then you can write:

```
if ( Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstLaunch )
{
  Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstLaunch = false;
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
  MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
}
```

The settings are stored in:

```
c:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\{Assembly CompanyName}\{Assembly Name}.Url__________
```

So be careful to set `Assembly CompanyName` in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` in the same section.

`Assembly Name` is from the application project properties (double click on this `Properties` section).

You can delete this file to test again.

Comment: When I run the program the message box shows up everytime. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to store that information somewhere

- File
- System registry
- Database
- Settings in application

Then read the value, and setup the firstTime flag prior to check.